# UICollectionView Protocol Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewController that presents a 'CollectionViewController', via an action button.

```
@objc func addPhoto() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let photoController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PhotoController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
    present(photoController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Inside the 'PhotoController', I'm trying to pass data back from this controller to the original viewController using the standard protocol procedure.

```
protocol PhotoControllerDelegate {
    func store(image: UIImage)
}

var delegate: PhotoControllerDelegate?

@objc func handleSave() {
    if let image = headerImage {
        delegate?.store(image: image)
    }

    ///Dimiss viewController
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now back inside the original viewController, I have re-instantiated the dismissed PhotoController:

```
let photoController = PhotoController()
```

and assigned the delegate inside viewDidLoad()

```
photoController.delegate = self
```

then provided the delegate method inside the original viewController:

```
func store(image: UIImage) {
    selectedPhotoImage.image = image
}
```

Issue is: this method is not even being called. 
I usually don't have any issues however this one has stumped me.

Any help would be great.

P.S. My viewControllers have a lot of extra junk inside, so couldn't post the complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add `delegate` as `self` to receive `protocol` event in that `viewController`

```
@objc func addPhoto() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let objVC = PhotoController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    objVC.delegate = self
    let photoController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objVC)
    present(photoController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to add `delegate` in same `viewController`. Use `extension` to make it clean code.

```
extension SourceController: PhotoControllerDelegate {
    func store(image: UIImage) {
        selectedPhotoImage.image = image
    }
}
```

Define `protocol` like below in `PhotoController`

```
public protocol PhotoControllerDelegate {
    func store(image: UIImage)
}
```

Comment: Does the protocol need to be public?

Comment: public protocol can only be used as an interface